# return the unique numbers in that list

Tags: python

Can you help me with this homework please?

> You are required to complete the function unique_list(l). where "l" is a list of numbers. the function is expected to return the unique numbers in that list.
>   Example:
>   (input : `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3`enter code here`,4,5,5,6]`)
>   output: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>   you are not allowed to change the variable names or their values or edit any other code, except the function's body, doing so may jeopardize your evaluation
>
> ---
>
> ```
> //no_list = [22,22,2,1,11,11,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,55,55,66]
>
> //def unique_list(l):  //code should be here
> //print(unique_list(no_list))
> ```

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with exactly? This is generally helpful and expected information (esp for a hw problem). The help section of the site should guide you if you are unsure how to improve your question. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: Instead of asking someone to do the work for you, try solving it yourself and if you still can't make it work, share your code and someone will try to fix your code.

Comment: @josephting I tried using set and it worked but I press test my code it's not the correct answer

Comment: @AzerAtyaoui Share the code you have so people can point out what you did wrong and fix it. It's ok if it's incorrect.

Comment: @busybear I tried the set method the result are ok , but the test code did not consider that as a correct answer

Comment: @busybear I tried this : no_list = [22,22,2,1,11,11,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,55,55,66]

def unique_list(l):
        my_set = set(no_list)
        my_new_list = list(my_set)
        print("List of unique numbers : ",my_new_list)
print(unique_list(no_list))

Comment: Edit the question with what you have tried instead of adding it in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code pick out the unique elements without changing the order:

```
no_list = [22,22,2,1,11,11,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,55,55,66]

def unique_list(l):  //code should be here
    return list({}.fromkeys(l).keys())

print(unique_list(no_list))  # [22, 2, 1, 11, 3, 4, 5, 55, 66]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will give the unique numbers in a list without changing the order.

```
>> def unique_list(l):
...     final_list = []
...     for num in l:
...             if num not in final_list:
...                     final_list.append(num)
...     return final_list
... 
>>> print (unique_list(no_list))
[22, 2, 1, 11, 3, 4, 5, 55, 66]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the `set` function and put it back into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **set** operation.

```
no_list = [22,22,2,1,11,11,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,55,55,66]
set(no_list)
[22,2,1,11,3,4,5,55,66]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are required to complete the function `average(x)`. where "x" is a list of numbers, and contains more than 3 numbers. the function is expected to return the average from that list.

You can change the numbers in the list `no_list` but you are not allowed to change the variable names or edit any other code, except the function's body, doing so may jeopardize your evaluation

```
no_list = [22,68,90,78,90,88]

def average(x):
       #complete the function's body to return the average

    
print(average(no_list))
```